# Passing different datatypes via a loop

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Lets say I have a function

```
template<typename T>
some_function(T a){
  // some operations..
}
```

I have a huge list of classes who objects i want to pass to the function one by one(Don't ask me why I'm forced to have it like that.)

```
class type1{ //.. whateever is necessary here...
};
class type2{ //.. whateever is necessary here...
};
class type3{ //.. whateever is necessary here...
};
class type4{ //.. whateever is necessary here...
};
.
.
and so on
```

Is there a way I can instantiate an object of each data and pass it to the function within a loop, rather than type one by one it manually.
(It would be better if the instantiation happens within the loop so that the object is local for every loop).
Any way to approach this problem other than typing it manually is welcome.

EDIT:

Since there were questions in the comments. Let me elaborate on the type of algorithm I am looking for.

Step 1: Pick a class `my_class in [type1,type2,...,typeN]`

Step 2: Instantiate an object of that class `my_class object`

Step 3: Pass it to the function `some_function(object)`

Step 4: Go to step 1 and pick the next class.

I hope I made things clear.

EDIT 2: I use c++11 . But I don't mind switching if it is needed

Comment: Sounds you rather need a tuple and unpacking a variadic template parameter pack.

Comment: What would you be looping over? Are your types literally named `type1`, `type2`, ...?

Comment: C++ Has no reflection, so what you're asking, which is basically iteration over types, doesn't exist in C++.
There are other methods of achieving similar things with MACROs/Code generation, but not intrinsically in the language...

Comment: @user0042 Can you explain in more detail.. And yeah.. I would loop over all the classes. I get to choose how the classes are named so they can literally be named type1, 2 etc

Comment: c++98, c++11, c++14 or c++17?

Comment: @Panch93 A [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) can be thought as a container for a certain set of types/values. Another viable solution might involve a `std::vector<std::any>` or such.

Comment: @user0042 I think the OP wants to enumerate (iterate over) all the existing hard-coded types (classes) in a loop and instantiate objects (somehow).

Comment: @Ron A tuple and unpacking can be used to achieve similar behavior at compile time. Typing out all the types would be necessary in one place though.

Comment: @user0042 Indeed so.

Comment: @user0042 I don't see how that would work.  But does `any` hold whatever is given to it ? Then I can manually instantiate and put in a `tuple` or `vector`. If it can accept different data types. It is better than what i have now. I have other areas in my code where i have to loop.

Comment: @ron Another thing I could think of would be virtual polymorphism and self registering all the various types with a global registrar (a factory function). Then the registrar instance is able to loop through all the various classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let me elaborate on the type of algorithm I am looking for.
>
> Step 1: Pick a class my_class in [type1,type2,...,typeN]
>
> Step 2: Instantiate an object of that class my_class object
>
> Step 3: Pass it to the function some_function(object)
>
> Step 4: Go to step 1 and pick the next class.

If you can use C++11 or newer, and if you can pass immediately the object instantiated to `some_function()`, you can simulate a loop with a variadic template type list as follows

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void repeatOverTypes ()
 {
   using unused=int[];

   (void)unused { 0, (some_function(Ts{}), 0)... };
 }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>

class type_1 { };
class type_2 { };
class type_3 { };
class type_4 { };


template <typename T>
void some_function (T a)
 { }

template <typename ... Ts>
void repeatOverTypes ()
 {
   using unused=int[];

   (void)unused { 0, (some_function(Ts{}), 0)... };
 }

int main ()
 {
   repeatOverTypes<type_1, type_2, type_3, type_4>();
 }
```

If you can use C++17, using folding `repeatOverTypes()` become simply

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void repeatOverTypes ()
 { (some_function(Ts{}), ...); }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP say

> I overlooked an important detail while trying to simplify the problem. I need to pass the objects by reference. So the `Ts{}` won't work ? What can i do ?

I see... well, I suppose you can (1) create the `Ts{}` object and store they in a container (a `std::tuple` seems to me an obvious container) and (2) pass to `some_function()` the values extracted from the tuple.

The point (1) is simple

```
std::tuple<Ts...> t { Ts{}... };
```

The point (2) heavily depend from the list of type (there are repetitions in "type1,type2,...,typeN" ?) and the exact language.

If all types in the list are different and you can use C++14, you can access the tuple values trough `std::get<Ts>(t)`; so the function can be written

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void repeatOverTypes ()
 {
   using unused=int[];

   std::tuple<Ts...> t { Ts{}... };

   (void)unused { 0, (some_function(std::get<Ts>(t)), 0)... };
 }
```

If there are repetitions, you have to access value via integer index, so you have to create a list of index and pass they to an helper function; something like

```
template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
void rotH (T & t, std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 {
   using unused=int[];

   (void)unused { 0, (some_function(std::get<Is>(t)), 0)... };

 }

template <typename ... Ts>
void repeatOverTypes ()
 {
   std::tuple<Ts...> t { Ts{}... };

   rotH(t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
 }
```

Unfortunately `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` are introduced in C++14 so, in C++11, you have to simulate they in some way.

As usual in C++17 is simpler; if you are sure (but really, really sure) that types are all different, the function is simply

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void repeatOverTypes ()
 { 
   std::tuple<Ts...> t { Ts{}... };

   (some_function(std::get<Ts>(t)), ...);
 }
```

In case of types collision, with integer sequence,

```
template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
void rotH (T & t, std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { (some_function(std::get<Is>(t)), ...); }

template <typename ... Ts>
void repeatOverTypes ()
 {
   std::tuple<Ts...> t { Ts{}... };

   rotH(t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing in your code. Specifically this line.`(void)unused { 0, (some_function(Ts{}), 0)... };`

Comment: @Panch93 - the line initialize an `int[]` and cast it to `void` to avoid a "not used" warning; inside there is a `0` (to avoid an error if you call `repeatOverTypes<>()`, so with an empty list of types) and `(some_function(Ts{}), 0)...` that is a call to `some_function()` with a `Ts{}` (one of the types in `Ts...` list) that is repeated (the final `...`) over all types; the final `0`, after a comma, is an integer because we are initializing an integer of arrays.

Comment: Ah.. This is exactly what I need. Cool!
One thing I don't understand is. Where exactly in the code is the object instantiated. ?
Shouldn't we pass something to `repeatOverTypes` ?

Comment: @Panch93 - the object instantiated are the temporary `Ts{}` (with default constructor but you can pass arguments). If you need to pass object received as argument in `repeatOverTypes()` I suppose the suggestion in the first comment of user0042: a tuple of `Ts...` is a good way.

Comment: @max66 Won't listing all these types require them to have the same signature applicable with `some_func()`? I wouldn't like to maintain a list of 100reds of class types in a tuple list at a central point. That sounds quite error prone for a design.

Comment: @user0042 - I'm agree, same signature required, and I'm agree, error prone. But I have done worse things in life :(

Comment: @max66 I was remembering the technique used in many unit testing frameworks, how the test cases are registered with a test runner, that doesn't want (need) to foresee all of the test cases that should be run.

Comment: I'm sorry. I overlooked an important detail while trying to simplify the problem. I need to pass the objects by reference. So the `Ts{}` won't work ? What can i do ?

Comment: @Panche - it's a problem; answer improved; hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a huge list of classes who objects i want to pass to the function one by one

As you seem to need handling **many types** and avoid to type them out hardcoded in a single place of your code (as provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47240683/8242698)), you should consider using dynamic polymorphism, interfaces and self-registering classes rather.

This is a well known technique when a uniform set of operations needs to be done over a lot of specific class types. Many unit testing frameworks use that in order to avoid that additional test cases need to be added at a central place, but just within the translation unit where they're defined.

---

Here's a sketch (untested) how to implement such:

Provide an interface to describe what needs to be done in `some_function()` uniquely:

```
struct IMyInterface {
     virtual ~IMyInterface() {}
     virtual void WhatNeedsToBeDone() = 0;
     virtual int WhatNeedsToBeKnown() const = 0;
};

void some_function(IMyInterface* intf) {
     if(intf->WhatNeedsToBeKnown() == 1) {
          intf->WhatNeedsToBeDone();
     }
}
```

Provide a singleton registrar keeping a map of functions to create your classes:

```
class MyRegistrar {
     MyRegistrar() {};
     using FactoryFunction = std::function<std::unique_ptr<IMyInterface> ()>;
     std::map<std::string, FactoryFunction> classFactories;
public:
     static MyRegistrar& ClassRegistry() {
         static MyRegistrar theRegistrar;
         return theRegistrar;
     };
     template<typename T>
     void registerClassFactory(
         FactoryFunction factory) {
         classFactories[typeid(T).name()] = factory;
     };

     template<typename T>
     std::unique_ptr<IMyInterface> createInstance() {
         return classFactories[typeid(T).name()]();
     }
     template<typename T>
     const FactoryFunction& factory() const {
          return classFactories[typeid(T).name()];
     } 
     std::vector<FactoryFunction> factories() const {
          std::vector<FactoryFunction> result;
          for(auto& factory : classFactories) {
              result.push_back(factory);
          }
          return result;
     } 
};
```

also provide a registration helper to make it easier registering the types with the global registrar

```
template<typename T>
struct RegistrationHelper {
     RegistrationHelper(
        std::function<std::unique_ptr<IMyInterface> ()> factoryFunc = 
            [](){ return std::make_unique<T>(); }) {
         MyRegistrar::ClassRegistry().registerClassFactory<T>(factoryFunc);
     }         
};
```

In your specific types you can use that like

```
class type1 : public IMyInterface {
    static RegistrationHelper<type1> reghelper;
public:
     void WhatNeedsToBeDone() override {}
     int WhatNeedsToBeKnown() const override { return 0; };
};

RegistrationHelper<type1> type1::reghelper;
```

You can also specialize to deviate from the default factory function:

```
enum Color { Red, Green };
class type1 : public IMyInterface {
    static RegistrationHelper<type1> reghelper;
    Color color_;
public:
     type1(Color color) : color_(color) {}
     void WhatNeedsToBeDone() override {}
     int WhatNeedsToBeKnown() const override { return 0; };
};

RegistrationHelper<type1> type1::reghelper(
    [](){ return std::make_unique<type1>(condition? Green : Red);   
    } -> std::function<std::unique_ptr<IMyInterface> ()>
);
```

---

To realize your iteration over all classes you can use

```
for(auto factory : MyRegistrar::ClassRegistry().factories()) {
    std::unique_ptr<IMyInterface> intf = factory();
    some_function(intf.get());
}
```